# How would I use string.split to recognize parameters in Python

Tags: python

So I need to know how I can split a string of words up to where my program can recognize parameters.

So this is what I have so far for this specific command:

```
if e.text.startswith("~ignore ") and (e.user == "SomeUser"):
  target = e.text.split(' ', 1)[1]
  c.send(message="Ignoring " + target)
  fh = open("ignore.txt", "a")
  fh.write(target + "\n")
  fh.close
```

Now I need it to read whatever comes after "~ignore" and whatever that is it would need to add it to an ignore list as well as send the message saying that the target is being ignored.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) in the standard library?

Comment: can u show some of the example text.how ur working.sample data and expected output

Comment: It'd be something like this:

"~ignore somebody_to_ignore" 

Then "somebody_to_ignore" would be set to the variable "target" and added to the ignore list

Comment: You have an XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - would you like to see a normal way to parse command line arguments in Python? The one mentioned by @MatthewTrevor I mean?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor How do you know it's Python 3 by the way?

Comment: Yes please, also I am using Python 2.7.5, which I actually can't update because of a different program I am using requires 2.7.

Comment: The default Python docs point to the 3.x documentation now. Here's a [Python 2.7 tutorial for argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
ignorelist = []
if e.text.startswith("~ignore ") and (e.user == "SomeUser"):
  _, target, ilist = e.text.split(' ', 2)
  ignorelist += ilist
  c.send(message="Ignoring " + target)
  fh = open("ignore.txt", "a")
  fh.write(target + "\n")
  fh.close
```